# access radio button value through form id

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom, radio-button

I am working on a website with several forms of radio buttons, one of which is like this:

```
<form id = "configuration">
    <ul>
        <li><input type="radio" name="configuration" id="0" value="0"/> GT Manual</li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="configuration" id="1" value="1"/> GT Automatic</li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

IS THERE a way (javascript) that I can access the value of the radio buttons directly, e.g.

```
var value = document.getElementById("configuration").configuration.value;
```

(here the first "configuration" is the form id while the second 'configuration' is the name, rather than looping through each element in the form to check which button is selected?

Thank you!

Comment: You should use the jquery for accessing the child element by the name of parent.

Comment: Sure, thanks. I was looking for a javascript method though.

Comment: use getElementsByName() instead !

Answer (score 2):

Get it like this...

```
var radios = document.getElementsByName('configuration');
 for (i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].type == 'radio' && radios[i].checked) {
        alert(radios[i].value);
    }
}
```

Comment: The existing code already gets the radio group, your new line one replaces that but doesn't work since they are `<input>` not `<configuration>`s. You should also avoid globals.

Comment: Thanks! It is perfectly valid, if you delete the 'Tag'. I was just wondering since radio button selection is unique amongst all elements which share a name, so there might be a function that gets the button checked directly. But it seems unlikely that there's none... :(

Answer (score 1):

No. You have to loop over the radio group to find out which one is selected. `.configuration` is a standard NodeList, not a 'subclass' with extra features for handling radio groups.

Comment: Hmmmmm, I was just wondering, since there can't be two buttons to be selected within the buttons with the same name, why isn't there such function that accesses the button selected directly? I mean, the implementation of such function might still be looping through the nodelist, but is there a html/javascript built-in function that does that?

Answer (score -1):

Since the Radio buttons are part of a group they have the same name are are identified by a distinct ID.
The answer provided by KyleK is perfectly valid.
However here is another way to do it
http://jsfiddle.net/9W76C/

```
if (document.getElementById('0').checked) {
   alert("GT Manual");
}
```

I would also suggest you use jquery...

Answer (score -1):

If you're using jQuery, you can do `$('#configuration input:checkbox').val();` to know which one is selected

Comment: The question is tagged `javascript` which says *Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected*. Even if that wasn't the case, your code would get the value of the **first checkbox** not the **checked radio button**